# Do I have to go through customs in Paris?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, airports, paris, layovers

I am travelling from Winnipeg, Canada to Toronto, to Paris, France and then to Edinburgh, Scotland.

I believe my plane to Edinburgh leaves from the same terminal that I arrive at in Charles-de-Gaulle.

My question is when and where will I have to go through customs? 
Is it likely that I will have to claim and re check my baggage?

I am travelling alone with my infant son and am worried about the timing of our short layover in France. I am hoping we can stay at the terminal we arrive at and wait for the next flight but I am unsure how it works.

Comment: What airline are you flying for the Toronto -> Paris and Paris -> Edinburgh legs?

Comment: I'm travelling Air France.

Answer (score 4):

As you are travelling on the same airline, and travelling from a non-Schengen country to another non-Schengen country you will NOT need to pass through immigration in Paris.

You bags *should* be checked all the way through to Edinburgh from Winnipeg.  If for some reason they claim they are not able to check them all the way through to Edinburgh I would suggest getting them to check them only to Toronto, where you will definitely be able to check them all the way through to Edinburgh.  You will almost certainly not need to do this, as they should check them all the way through, but given that you will be on a different airline for the first leg anything is possible...

The only place you will need to pass through immigration is once you arrive in Edinburgh, and this is also the only place you should need to collect your bags.